# ASP CascadingDropDown control does not reload on postback

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager, cascadingdropdown

I have a web form page that contains two modes: View and Edit. When in view mode, I do not load the CascadingDropDown control. When in edit mode, I do load the CascadingDropDown control.

When in edit mode, the user also has the ability to click another edit button to enable a set of checkboxes and then click update. Clicking these buttons while in edit mode causes the web form to be posted back to the server for process. When the form is redisplayed (still in edit mode) some dropdowns have values to choose and others have nothing. I programatically create the cascading drop down controls in the pre-render phase ever time the page is loaded. I noticed the AjaxControlToolkit script code is not in the output HTML when the user posts back but it is the first time they come into this page.

Seems like I need a way to get the Toolkit to load its scripts after postback? I cannot use update panels either because new dropdowns are added after postback.